# Replace QML file content by another one

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have the following `main.qml` file:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow 
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

   Button 
   {
        text: "Button"
        onClicked: qml_file_loader.loadFile("help.qml");
   }
}
```

When the button is clicked, I would like to inject the content of the `help.qml` file. What I am currently doing is opening another window, by loading the file with the following code in `loadFile(const QString)`:

```
void QMLFileLoader::loadFile(const QString page)
{
    m_view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(page));
    m_view.show();
}
```

What would I need to do in order to replace the current `QML` file?

The objective behind all this is to separate the `UI` from the logic that will handle the data updating the `QML` files. The `C++` code is a library that will be used in other projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the [QML `Loader` item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) what you are looking for?

You can use a `Loader` as a content item in the view and use it to load different files.
You can even easily receive signals from the loaded items and so on...

See the above mentioned documentation for further details.

Below a minimal example taken from the documentation:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 200;
    height: 200

    Loader { id: pageLoader }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: pageLoader.source = "Page1.qml"
    }
}
```

To use it within an application window is pretty easy indeed.
Your logic can simply update the `pageLoader.source` property to update the UI, as you mentioned.

Comment: This seems to be the most practical way to implement my logic.